# CUDA record and wait for event not working?

Tags: c, asynchronous, cuda

Following the skeleton of my setup. Executed like this it doesn't give the correct result. This is most likely due to the async data transfers which haven't finished when the kernel uses them. I implemented a "failsafe" version with the preprocessor `if-else` statement. When translating the `else` part the program runs fine. I don't get it. Why that?

The `in1`, `out1` ,... are just placeholders. Of course they point to different containers each iteration of the for loop. so that async transfer can take place. But within on iteration the `out1` used by the transfer and the one by the kernel are the same.

```
  cudaStream_t streams[2];
  cudaEvent_t  evCopied;

  cudaStreamCreate(&streams[0]); // TRANSFER
  cudaStreamCreate(&streams[1]); // KERNEL

  cudaEventCreate(&evCopied);

  // many iterations
  for () {

    // Here I want overlapping of transfers with previous kernel
    cudaMemcpyAsync( out1, in1, size1, cudaMemcpyDefault, streams[0] );
    cudaMemcpyAsync( out2, in2, size2, cudaMemcpyDefault, streams[0] );
    cudaMemcpyAsync( out3, in3, size3, cudaMemcpyDefault, streams[0] );

#if 1
    // make sure host thread doesn't "run away"
    cudaStreamSynchronize( streams[1] );
    cudaEventRecord( evCopied , streams[0] );
    cudaStreamWaitEvent( streams[1] , evCopied , 0);
#else
    // this gives the correct results
    cudaStreamSynchronize( streams[0] );
    cudaStreamSynchronize( streams[1] );
#endif

    kernel<<< grid , sh_mem , streams[1] >>>(out1,out2,out3);

  }
```

Please don't post answers suggesting a rearrangement of the setup. Something like, divide your kernels into several ones and issue them in separate stream.

Comment: Presumably the kernel launch syntax is just a mistake?

Comment: yes, the kernel launch is also just a placeholder. The for-loop as well.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing -- or at least the use of an event to synchronize two streams -- should work. It is basically impossible to say why your *actual* code doesn't work because you have chosen not to post it, and the devil is always in the detail.

However, here is a complete, runnable example which I think is using the streams API in a fashion similar to what you are trying to do and which works correctly:

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef unsigned int uint;

template<uint bsz>
__global__ void kernel(uint * a, uint * b, uint * c, const uint N)
{
    __shared__ volatile uint buf[bsz];
    uint tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    uint stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    uint val = 0;
    for(uint i=tid; i<N; i+=stride) {
        val += a[i] + b[i];
    }
    buf[threadIdx.x] = val; __syncthreads();

#pragma unroll
    for(uint i=(threadIdx.x+warpSize); (threadIdx.x<warpSize)&&(i<bsz); i+=warpSize)
        buf[threadIdx.x] += buf[i];

    if (threadIdx.x < 16) buf[threadIdx.x] += buf[threadIdx.x+16];
    if (threadIdx.x < 8)  buf[threadIdx.x] += buf[threadIdx.x+8];
    if (threadIdx.x < 4)  buf[threadIdx.x] += buf[threadIdx.x+4];
    if (threadIdx.x < 2)  buf[threadIdx.x] += buf[threadIdx.x+2];
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) c[blockIdx.x] += buf[0] + buf[1];

}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int nruns = 16, ntransfers = 3;
    const int Nb = 32, Nt = 192, Nr = 3000, N = Nr * Nb * Nt;
    const size_t szNb = Nb * sizeof(uint), szN = size_t(N) * sizeof(uint);
    size_t sz[4] = { szN, szN, szNb, szNb };

    uint * d[ntransfers+1];
    for(int i=0; i<ntransfers+1; i++)
        gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void **)&d[i], sz[i]));
    uint * a = d[0], * b = d[1], * c = d[2], * out = d[3];

    for(uint i=0; i<N; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i] = 1; 
        if (i<Nb) c[i] = 0;
    }

    uint * _d[3];
    for(int i=0; i<ntransfers; i++)
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **)&_d[i], sz[i])); 
    uint * _a = _d[0], * _b = _d[1], * _c = _d[2];

    cudaStream_t stream[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&stream[i]));

    cudaEvent_t sync_event;
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&sync_event)); 

    uint results[nruns];
    for(int j=0; j<nruns; j++) {
        for(int i=0; i<ntransfers; i++)
            gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(_d[i], d[i], sz[i], cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[0]));

        gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(sync_event, stream[0]));
        gpuErrchk(cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream[1], sync_event, 0));

        kernel<Nt><<<Nb, Nt, 0, stream[1]>>>(_a, _b, _c, N);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(out, _c, szNb, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream[1]));
        gpuErrchk(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream[1]));

        results[j] = uint(0);
        for(int i=0; i<Nb; i++) results[j]+= out[i];
    }

    for(int j=0; j<nruns; j++) 
        fprintf(stdout, "%3d: ans = %u\n", j, results[j]);

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
    return 0;
}
```

The kernel is a "fused vector addition/reduction", just nonsense, but it relies on the last of the three inputs being zeroed prior to kernel execution to produce the correct answer, which should simply be twice the number of input data points. As in your example, the kernel execution and asynchronous input array copying are in different streams, so the copying and the execution can potentially overlap. There is no sane reason to copy the first two large inputs at every iteration in this case, other than to introduce delay before the last copy (which is the critical one) is done and increase the chance it will incorrectly overlap with the kernel. This might be where you are going wrong, because I don't believe the CUDA memory model guarantees that it is safe to asynchronously modify memory being accessed by a running kernel. *If* that is what you are trying to do, then expect it to fail. But without seeing real code, it is impossible to say more.

With that out of the way, you can see for yourself that the kernel won't produce the correct result without the `cudaStreamWaitEvent` to synchronize the two streams prior to kernel launch. The only difference between the your pseudo code and this example is the location of the `cudaStreamSynchronize` on the execution stream. Here I placed it after the kernel launch in order to make sure the kernel finishes before the transfer to gather the results back to the host. That could be the critical difference, but again, no real code equal no real code analysis....

All I can suggest is you play with this example to get a feel for how it works. I understand there is the possibility to profile asynchronous code without the profiling artificially serializing the execution streams in very recent versions of Nsight for Windows. That might be able to help you diagnose your problem if you can't work out the problem from this example or your own code.